# Add more bars into barchart EazeGraph

Tags: java, android

I am following this link for displaying of animated graphs for android.
But following the example, i am unable to add more bars into the graph. The example only gives 8 while i would need 10.

Link to page : https://github.com/blackfizz/EazeGraph

This is the example given by the site

```
 mBarChart.addBar(new BarModel(2.3f, 0xFF123456));
 mBarChart.addBar(new BarModel(2.f,  0xFF343456));
 mBarChart.addBar(new BarModel(3.3f, 0xFF563456));
 mBarChart.addBar(new BarModel(1.1f, 0xFF873F56));
 mBarChart.addBar(new BarModel(2.7f, 0xFF56B7F1));
 mBarChart.addBar(new BarModel(2.f,  0xFF343456));
 mBarChart.addBar(new BarModel(0.4f, 0xFF1FF4AC));
 mBarChart.addBar(new BarModel(4.f,  0xFF1BA4E6));
```

I do not understand what does the back values does too.

Would any kind soul do explain and help me out? Thanks!

**UPDATE**: Found out maybe it's due to my s4 screen size unable to fit 10 bars in,
in that case, how would one lower the space between the bar gaps? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the `egFixedBarWidth` - attribute to `false` and the `egEnableScroll` - attribute to `false`, then you can use the `egBarMargin` - attribute to set the margin between each bar. The rest will be calculated dynamically, based on your maximum screen size.

And the last value is the color in which the bar will be drawn.

Comment: Thanks Blackfizz(P)! :D